# Monophone vs triphone in HMM

Tags: speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models, gmm

In speech recognition how monophone is represented differently from triphone in HMM?

Monophone is assumed to be context-independent and triphone is context dependent. But in HMM states are chained so doesn't it mean that even monophone is context-dependent because in HMM one state transit to another state with some probability. I am confused here.